# Export SAP BW data to SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, netweaver, sap-bw

I am trying to bring data from SAP NetWeaver BW cube to SQL SERVER. I'm following this document TO ACHIEVE THIS
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185161(v=bts.10).aspx

But I am unable to get **.NET Framework Data Provider for mySAP Business Suite for my SQL SERVER 2012.**

Any help on this or any other method to achieve this?

I use SSIS as my ETL tool. I also have openhub licence.